# React Native Android GCM (Google Cloud Messaging)

Tags: react-native

Currently React Native [supports](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#content) Push Notifications in iOS. Setting that up seems straightforward, however achieving the same functionality in Android seems much more challenging. Currently I don't see anything in the docs regarding setting up GCM (Google's push notification service) in React Native. The [only module](https://github.com/bh5-pods/react-native-gcm) I have seen for GCM allows the service only on iOS. How would I get GCM in my React Native Android app?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3423#issuecomment-148343744

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This module looks like it could provide Google Cloud Messaging functionality for now until Facebook releases one that is bundled into the main React Native package.

https://github.com/oney/react-native-gcm-android

Answer (score 2):

Here ist another project on github with push support for android and ios:

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

Comment: Can you post an example or implementation?

Comment: Looks like currently on Android, this one doesn't work when the app is not open. [Ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100087/unable-to-get-notification-if-app-is-in-closed-state-using-react-native-push-not/38100324#38100324)

Comment: However, it is the one used in the [Facebook F8 app](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/).