# unable to get notification if app is in closed state using react-native-push-notification

Tags: react-native

Using react-native-push-notification [ref](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

I am send message to GCM using nodejs node-android module, my message is successfully send to GCM server but notification is not displayed in receiver device
for ${applicationId} i am replacing my GCM package(com.test)
if app is in open state i am able to get notifications.