# Unable to receive notification when app closed

Tags: push-notification, react-native, onesignal

How I can receive push notification when app was closed?
When I roll up app notification received, but when I close - no. 
I`m using react-native and onesignal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to get notification if app is in closed state using react-native-push-notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100087/unable-to-get-notification-if-app-is-in-closed-state-using-react-native-push-not)

Comment: I'm looking a same thing, did you succeed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You should look how to intent a service in react-native. A service work apart from the main thread of the app, so when the app is closes the service is steal working.